# modify Response Object returbed by an endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets, interceptor

I have an endpoint method that returns a List of Items, I wonder how can I intercept this list to apply some modifications for example:

```
@PostMapping(value="/someUrl")
public List<Items> find(@RequestBody Command cmd){
   //do something
   return arrayListOfItems;
}
```

I tried to do using `HandlerInterceptor`, is it possible to get the returned list from the `HttpServletResponse` here?, if not what is the best solution ?

```
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object o, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws IOException {
                    
           //how can I get the returned List<Items> and modify it here, before returning it to the client 
}
```

Comment: can you not do that within `find` method itself -- before returning `list`? because that would be straight-forward way.

Comment: I'm trying to modify the returned value of many endpoints based on certain criteria, which is not the best solution to change the whole code...